# Link to remote issue is not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the [live demo](http://code.runnable.com/Vw_xsf9_qaZaAZOy/update-div-select-options-rails-4)

I'm trying to show listbox using remote actions just searching params, but is not working.

**Clients_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @client.new
end

def search_city 
  @cities = City.where('id= ?',params[:city_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end
```

**search_city.js.erb**

```
$("#test").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "city_results"))%>");
```

**Models**

```
Client.rb
  belongs_to :city

City.rb
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :clients

State.rb
  has_many :cities
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :clients do
   match 'search_city',:via =>[:get], :on => :collection
end
```

**_form.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Get list cities", {:action => "search_city"}, :remote => true, :class => "button-link" %>

<div id = "test">Here this text will be replaced</div>
```

**_city_results.erb**

```
<%= select_tag "example",options_for_select(@cities.collect { |p| [p.name,p.id] }) %>
```

Here complete log:

```
Started GET "/clients/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-14 17:31:03 -0500
 Processing by ClientsController#new as HTML
 Completed 200 OK in 133ms (Views: 107.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
 Rendered client_management/clients/new.html.erb within layouts/application (21.6ms)

Started GET "/clients/search_city?city_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-14 16:43:55 -0500
Processing by ClientManagement::ClientsController#search_city as JS
 Parameters: {"city_id"=>"1"}
 Province Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `states`.* FROM `states` WHERE `states`.`city_id` = 1
 Rendered clients/partials/_city_results.erb (1.9ms)
 Rendered clients/search_city.js.erb (2.9ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

INFO

```
SELECT `states`.* FROM `states` WHERE `states`.`city_id` = 1
RESULT: 1 (exist value)
```

PROBLEM:

Is not showing the select tag with options.
When I check if params are sended everything is ok but in the view  is not replaced.

Need to install a gem?

Is just working with simple text without but need rails code.

I tried this:

```
$('#province').html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => 'clients/partials/city_results' ) %>");
$('#province').show();
```

Comment: pass your @cities to your partial 'clients/partials/city_results'

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: sorry, you don't need that, you're using an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def search city
  ....
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't check the logs. Could u update your question with the new logs?

Comment: As you can see from the log it has nothing to do with js. `name` attribute is not set properly.

Comment: Jacob in the logs you should see the request going to the proper route. If it doesn't then no matter what you put in the controller. If it reaches the controller then you should see that `search_city.js.erb` is rendered. If it's not, then doesn't matter what your `search_city.js.erb contains`.

Comment: Could you send a bit longer log? The part after `province load`

Comment: ok, I don't know if this is going to work, but change the double quotes around your "city_results" to be single quotes. I recall having an issue like this a long time ago.

Comment: Jacob, the `js.erb` is finally rendered, so you can start looking for problems in that file. Try this: `$("#province").html('<%= j render partial: "clients/partials/city_results", locals: { city: @city } %>');` I don't know how you access local variables in the partial, but you may have to set it. For testing if it really calls the `js.erb` file you could comment out the 2 lines and put `alert('haha');` to see if the window pops up.